# Assembly code not working as expected

Tags: assembly, nasm, qemu

I have this code

```
call print_char
mov ah, 0x0e
mov al, 'O'

print_char:
mov ah, 0x0e
mov al, 'J'
int 0x10
ret

jmp $
times 510 -($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

The output that I get from it is J when it should be JO, why doesn't this happen? I called the `print_char` label then when it hits `ret` it should go and do whatever is after `call print_char` shouldn't it?

Comment: What makes you believe it should be `JO`?  You move an O into AL, then fall through to the print_char func where you replace it with a J.  It does exactly what you've told it to do.

Answer (score 2):

> it should go and do whatever is after call print_char shouldn't it?

Sure, and what is after `call print_char`?

```
mov ah, 0x0e
mov al, 'O'   ; set al='O'

print_char:
mov ah, 0x0e
mov al, 'J'   ; overwrite al with 'J'. the second interrupt hasn't been executed yet.
int 0x10
```

And then `ret` gets executed again without a corresponding `call`. I'd say ditch your current design and change it to something clearer:

```
jmp main

print_char:
mov ah, 0x0e
int 0x10
ret

main:    
mov al ,'J'
call print_char
mov al,'O'
call print_char

jmp $
times 510 -($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

Comment: I suggest to indent lines that are not labels, but this is just a matter of style.